# While multi-threading in JS -- time latency shows up in fluent message dispatching

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I'm using multi-threading in my web-application to render some geometric
diagrams involving (very) long loops.

During early (and raw) implementations, I found that reducing the number of
parameters being passed from the multi-threader to the related
listener really sped up the whole loop.  It also let the web application dispatch the events queue with fluency, so that the onclick event halts as I click the mouse button down. It works great, as it's expected to in these cases.

Now I am programming a new situation involving parsing user-defined formulas.  Say 'z^2-z+1' for example, inside the same long loops as mentioned before.

I expected the parser to slow down the dispatching of messages from the multi-tasker to the listener, but I can't figure out the reason why the same onclick event is being processed quite later after the mouse button has been pushed.

It seems that **the parser itself is out of sync with the multi-threader dispatch process**, causing long time intervals of latency delays, where events can't be processed immediately as usual.

Increasing the number of messages sent from the multi-tasker to the listener
didn't work as well as decreasing the number of messages. In the first case, I failed to guarantee a frequent exchange of messages due to the counter-effect of making the loop running quite slower and due to the high number of messages sent to the listener.

On the contrary, decreasing such number affected the communication from multi-tasker to listener because few events are sent and so they are then processed a long later.

Naturally, according to my early success, the number of parameters passed to the listener remained the same.

It seems I'm facing a different aspect of the same problem and I guess I should find the way to forward some stopping command to the parser.

Any trick to keep the events queue dispatching fluently again ?

Thank you

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what your question actually is. I would recommend you trim the question down to just the pertinent details, and include a minimum amount of code to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "multi-threading"? are you using Web Workers?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to represent it through a specific example. But I'll try.

Say you have a loop in multi-threader object (this code works nice as expected):

```
var _glob_stop = 0 ;
for ( var _i = 0 ; _i < 10000 ; _i++ )
{
    // plot points on a canvas
    if ( _glob_stop ) break ;
}
```

In the case above, the state of _glob_stop changes IMMEDIATELY due to an onclick event fired by the user.

Now in this new situation:

```
for ( var _i = 0 ; _i < 10000 ; _i++ )
{
    // parse a user-defined formula, say 'z^2-z+1'
    // plot the resulting point on a canvas
    if ( _glob_stop ) break ;
}
```

Now the response from firing the onclick event is caught later, long after, from the dispatcher.

Comment: thanks for editing and correcting those minor errors